# I am getting the cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Tags: angular

I have created a new project but it is not allowing me to ng serve it. It is giving me the 'cannot find module @angular/compiler-cli' error.

I've tried clearing the cache, deleting the node_modules folder from within my project but I am still getting the error. I had previously run npm install -g @angular/cli as well. My package.json file shows @angular/compiler-cli listed as a devDependency. Here's what I get when I try npm install after removing the node_modules folder:

npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."dist":{"shasum":"25b'

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "login-page",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: does this folder exist for you? .\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli

Comment: Try below steps again..1. npm install npm@latest -g  2.npm install -g @angular/cli 3. npm install update 4. Clean npm cache: npm cache clean --force ...You can check at http://musttoknow.com/how-to-setup-local-environment-for-angular-projects-with-angular-cli-example/ for creating project in angular using cli...

Comment: @AkberIqbal I don't currently have the \node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli folder. Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: when you do `ng version` from command prompt, what do you get? if you get nothing, then you would need to install angular!

Comment: Here's an update of what I have tried so far: npm install npm@latest -g, npm remove -g @angular/cli, npm install -g @angular/cli@latest, rm -rf node_modules dist, npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest, npm install, npm i nyc (due to: npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives. Then I tried: npm uninstall angular-cli -g, npm uninstall angular-cli --save, npm install @angular-devkit/core --save-dev. Getting same error.

Comment: @AkberIqbal here's what I get with `ng version`:

Comment: @AkberIqbal: Angular CLI: 7.3.0
Node: 8.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: <error>
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Package                                Version
@angular-devkit/architect       0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            7.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      7.3.0
@angular/cli                    7.3.0
@schematics/angular             7.3.0
@schematics/update              0.13.0
rxjs       <error>
typescript     <error>

Comment: there is a `\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli` folder present, right?

Comment: @AkberIqbal I do have a cli folder within /node_modules/@angular but not specifically a compiler-cli folder.

Comment: @AkberIqbal I just installed the compiler-cli folder and tried serving it and it still gives me the same "cannot find module 'angular/compiler-cli'".

Comment: Npm install should create this too... The absence of this folder is giving you the error - If you go to a different folder and npm install @angular/Cli... Can you confirm that compiler-Cli folder gets created?

Comment: I went to another project folder and did npm install @angular/cli and it worked fine. Tried it in the original project folder and it gave me the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I went back after some time and tried the suggestions that were provided previously and it finally worked. I ended up deleting the package-lock.json file within /node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli. Not 100% sure if it had anything to do with it but did npm install then ng serve and it worked for me. Thank you!